# Incorrect Pattern Image Generation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Content: Image Processing in OpenCV C++.

**The Requirement** is to create tiles of *Mat* pattern of size 256 X 256 on an outer *Mat* Image. The user specifies the width and the height of the outer *Mat* Image.

**To do this**, I created the below OpenCV C++ function:

```
Mat GenerateDiagonalFade(int width, int height)
{

// Creating a Mat Image in user defined dimension
Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0)); 


//Looping through all rows and columns of the outer Image
for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; row ++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; col ++)
    {   

       //Here, I am giving the condition to access the pixel values

       //The pattern should be 255 X 255 and they must fill in the entire image

        if ((row % 256 + col % 256) <= 255)
        {

            image.at<uchar>(row, col) = (row % 256 + col  % 256);
        }

        else
        {
            //Here is where I get error
            image.at<uchar>(row, col) = abs(row % 256 - col % 256);
        }
    }
}
return image;
}
```

If you can see the else statement above, I tried to make the inverse of the first condition and make the value absolute.

**The output** I get is as seen below:[image]

**The Expected Output** is the inverse of the first part of the diagonal. Darker to lighter shade towards the diagonal.

I tried replacing  `abs(row % 256 - col % 256);`  with many statements. I am struct with the output. 
The changes should be made only in the else statement. Rest of my code is correct as half of my output( top diagonal) is right.

I appreciate any help from you in order to solve this. Trust me, it's quite interesting to work out all graphical[X-Y axis] and mathematical calculations[pixel access] to get the desired output.

Comment: First of all, divide and conquer. Solve the generation of a single tile first. Then use that to generate the whole image (e.g. by simply copying it to the appropriate ROI). | The size 255x255 seems rather odd -- one would expect 256x256. Care to elaborate on the reasons? | Can you provide an image that shows how the tile should look like?

Comment: The same image is being generated again in loop so, the problem is not with the number of times the image is being generated. The error is in the pattern. The image should look like the first part of the diagonal. I have clearly explained the expected  output image in my question.

Comment: And that's exactly why I'm suggesting you reduce the problem to generating the pattern of a single full-size tile. | I honestly don't get what you mean by "look like the first part of the diagonal" -- what's "first part" referring to? Do you mean that the top left corner should be black, diagonal medium intensity and bottom right full white?

Comment: Did you try `510 - (row % 256 + col  % 256)`?

Comment: @DivyaMaheswaran Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/DdrGIGH.png)?

Comment: @DivyaMaheswaran Or [this](https://i.imgur.com/q1uRV40.png)?

Comment: Yes, the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would begin by splitting the problem into two parts:

- Generating a single tile containing the correct pattern
- Using that tile (or algorithm) to generate the whole image

---

### Generating a Tile

The goal is to generate a 256x256 grayscale image containing a gradient such that:

- Top left corner is all black
- Bottom right corner is all black
- The diagonal going from bottom left to top right is all white

You got the part above the diagonal right, but let's inspect that anyway.

The coordinates of the top left corner are (0, 0) and we expect intensity of 0. --> `row + col == 0`

The coordinates of one end of the diagonal are (255, 0) and we expect intensity of 255. --> `row + col == 255`

The other end of the diagonal is at (0, 255) -> `row + col == 255`

Let's try another point on the diagonal, (254,1) --> again `row + col == 255`

OK, now a point just above the diagonal, (254,0) -> `row + col == 254` -- slightly less white, as we would expect.

Next, let's try a point just below the diagonal, say (255, 1) --> `row + col == 256`. If we cast this to an 8 bit integer, we get a 0, yet we expect 254, just like in the previous case.

Finally, bottom right corner (255, 255) -> `row + col == 510`. If we cast this to an 8 bit integer, we get a 254, yet we expect 0.

Let's try something:

- `256 + 254 == 510`
- `510 + 0 == 510`

And we see an algorithm:
* If the sum of `row + col` is less than 256, then use the sum
* Otherwise subtract the sum from 510 and use the result

Sample code:

```
cv::Mat make_tile()
{
    int32_t const TILE_SIZE(256);
    cv::Mat image(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, CV_8UC1);
    for (int32_t r(0); r < TILE_SIZE; ++r) {
        for (int32_t c(0); c < TILE_SIZE; ++c) {
            int32_t sum(r + c);
            if (sum < TILE_SIZE) {
                image.at<uint8_t>(r, c) = static_cast<uint8_t>(sum);
            } else {
                image.at<uint8_t>(r, c) = static_cast<uint8_t>(2 * (TILE_SIZE - 1) - sum);
            }            
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

Single tile:

[image: Single tile]

---

### Generating Image of Tiles

Now that we have a complete tile, we can simply generate the full image by iterating over tile-sized ROIs of the target image, and copying a tile ROI of identical size to them.

Sample code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

cv::Mat make_tile()
{
    int32_t const TILE_SIZE(256);
    cv::Mat image(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, CV_8UC1);
    for (int32_t r(0); r < TILE_SIZE; ++r) {
        for (int32_t c(0); c < TILE_SIZE; ++c) {
            int32_t sum(r + c);
            if (sum < TILE_SIZE) {
                image.at<uint8_t>(r, c) = static_cast<uint8_t>(sum);
            } else {
                image.at<uint8_t>(r, c) = static_cast<uint8_t>(2 * (TILE_SIZE - 1) - sum);
            }            
        }
    }
    return image;
}

int main()
{   
    cv::Mat tile(make_tile());

    cv::Mat result(600, 800, CV_8UC1);

    for (int32_t r(0); r < result.rows; r += tile.rows) {
        for (int32_t c(0); c < result.cols; c += tile.cols) {
            // Handle incomplete tiles
            int32_t end_r(std::min(r + tile.rows, result.rows));
            int32_t end_c(std::min(c + tile.cols, result.cols));
            // Get current target tile ROI and source ROI of same size
            cv::Mat target_roi(result(cv::Range(r, end_r), cv::Range(c, end_c)));
            cv::Mat source_roi(tile(cv::Range(0, target_roi.rows), cv::Range(0, target_roi.cols)));
            // Copy the tile
            source_roi.copyTo(target_roi);
        }
    }

    cv::imwrite("gradient.png", tile);
    cv::imwrite("gradient_big.png", result);
}
```

Complete image:

[image: Complete image]

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks Dan!